# RF layout good practices

Tags: rf

I was doing an 868 MHz transmitter layout, and as always, I have placed the filter and matching inductors and capacitors in a "straight line" from the TX output pin to the antenna. See picture below.

[image: TX output filter]

I was once told by and more experienced RF guy, that TX outputs should always be in a straight line to the antenna, if possible, because sharp turns in the signal path could cause several dB of loss. But, say that due to limited space, it was not possible to make the TX signal path a straight line.

Would it still be possible to make a good RF design, if not using a straight line, and what are the best design principles in such case?

EDIT: After feedback, I have changed the layout to the following:

[image: Layout reworked]

Is this more correct now?

Should I worry about orientation of inductors in relation to their magnetic fields? I have seen application notes from manufactures where they pointed out that it was very important to orient inductors correctly, or else their magnetic field would affect the inductor behavior.

Snapshot from TRC105 reference design (NOT the chip I am using for this design):

[image: TRC105 Reference Design]

Comment: Yes it's still possible to make a good design. I would instead of using sharp turns, use round corners. If you want to do this RF design the proper way you need an EM modeling tool. Such a tool can show you in a graph how good your design is and you can tweak the design and see the result. It takes some learning of course. One such tool is Keysight Momentum, it is expensive though. There are also some (limited) freeware tools, I sometimes use QUCS for filter design but it can also simulate simple 3d structures.

Comment: @FakeMoustache, I don't need an EM tool to know that the excess capacitance from one or two 90 degree bends would not be nearly as much as the excess capacitance from all those component pads.

Comment: @ThePhoton Maybe you don't since you have experience and/or "feeling for it". Beginners often lack this. Then an EM simulator might help or even better: someone with more experience. But they're not always available. An EM simulator can be. I agree though that this layout is far from optimal. But heck, it's only 868 MHz ;-) My colleages deal with 60 GHz, then you really need an EM simulator.

Comment: In my area, we only started using EM simulators at around 8 Gb/s. Of course an antenna feed could be fussier than a digital connection, even at lower frequencies.

Comment: 868MHz is not that high frequency, I don't think there might be a need for EM simulation. EM simulations are mostly used for long signal traces coupling but there is no long traces in this circuit. Arranging the components in right position will be enough I think.

Comment: "sharp turns in the signal path could cause several dB of loss."  Somebody gave you bad advice.  At 868 MHz, maybe, MAYBE a small fraction of a dB.  And that would apply to both an Rx and a Tx path.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While avoiding 90 degree bends is a good idea, for designs below maybe 1 GHz, my experience is that it isn't an absolute requirement.

More important improvements you could make in your design:

- Increase track width (which probably means increasing dielectric thickness to maintain the same \$Z_0\$). Wider tracks will have lower loss. Also, if you increase the track width to match the width of the pads of your inductors and capacitors it will reduce the excess capacitance at those pads.
- Rotate C32, C33, C41, L7 to be parallel to the signal path, so that their ground connections are nearer to the signal trace. (C41 and L7 could be placed on either side alongside C31) The goal is to reduce the loop area between the signal path and the return path for currents flowing through those shunt elements.

  One of the key things you'll learn in your first 2 or 3 RF design projects is to always always consider the return path when making layout decisions.
- Increase clearance between silkscreen and pads. Your inductor footprint looks like if there is any mis-registration between silkscreen and solder mask you will end up with ink on the pads.
- Probably move C36 to shorten the distance between L2 and C36, but without a schematic I'm not sure about this.

Comment: Yes Photon has great points here. Also note the thin traces from ground vias. According to Saturn PCB Toolkit, a 6mil trace on 60mil FR4 has an impedance of 140 Ohms at 1GHz. This equates to a resistance at these frequencies. So those thin traces are like little resistors between each element.

Comment: @rdtsc, I disagree about analyzing the narrow traces as equivalent to resistors. Certainly the correspondence isn't just to a resistor with value equal to \$Z_0\$.

Comment: Do I need to care about maitaining Z0 between the components in the signal path, when the traces between them are very short compared to the wavelength?

Comment: @JakobJ, probably not really, but you should do that before you start worrying about things like the effect of bends.

Comment: @ThePhoton I have changed my design, now I hope it is more optimal. And added a question that popped into my mind about Inductors. PLease see edits.

Comment: @JakobJ, It would be better to make a new post to ask the question about the inductors.

Comment: Incidentally, before I saw your added question I had thought, "I wonder if those are shielded inductors?" You could indeed have a problem with that layout due  to magnetic coupling between inductors. If you didn't design the circuit to use the inductors coupled, you'll probably want more space between the inductors so they don't couple too much, and/or place them at right angles to each other.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't avoid turns in HF signal path altogether, the next best thing is to avoid *sharp* turns.

From [TI High-Speed Layout Guidelines](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/scaa082/scaa082.pdf):

> Avoid right-angle bends in a trace and try to route them at least with two 45° corners. To minimize any impedance change, **the best routing would be a round bend**

Comment: But, there has to be some rules of thumb, that can be applied, of how much loss (reflection) to expect, when during a sharp turn ?

Comment: Oh, found something on google, apparently impedance can be kept using Mitered Corners. Remember to actually have learned this before, but it somehow got lost again.

Comment: @JakobJ Maybe it makes sense to add [this link](https://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Chamfered+Routing) here.

Comment: Sometimes actual measurements help: www.ultracad.com/articles/90deg.pdf - this stacks up with Intel guidance (from the early 2000s) where they stated in a design guide that 90 degree turns had little effect for up to 2.5Gb/sec data transmission. I will see if I can find that design guide. That is not to say that doing rounded corners is not the best possible, but is it necessary for the required performance is a different question.