# In PCB RF layouts, should low-pass elements be oriented parallel or perpendicular to the feed?

Tags: pcb-design, rf

This is a portion of a 900 MHz 50 Ω controlled-impedance layout for a radio antenna feed.

[image: PCB top layer example]

The above layout is based roughly on something like this Pi filter:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs9RsC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have laid out the capacitors *perpendicular* to the feed so that their signal-side terminals are in the feed path. The top-layer ground clearance distance is set so that it is greater than the distance to the underlying ground layer, thus making the underlying ground layer, dielectric thickness, and trace width responsible for controlling impedance.

I was reviewing [this post about best RF layout practices](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/226526/2028) and noted in [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/226594/2028) (second point) that it was recommended to place these components *parallel* to the feed line to keep loop area as small as possible.

Would it improve the design (in terms of losses, harmonics, etc.) to follow this advice? I am skeptical because it would require a "T-shaped" addition to the feed line to connect the capacitors. (I perceive this to be less optimal for the signal, but I have no evidence for that.)

I don't have signal simulation software for this sort of thing yet, but I'd like to improve understanding of these types of design decisions. I am interested in knowing how to make these decisions seem less esoteric.

Comment: If you rotated them perpendicularly you'd have to also move them down and that would increase the loop area by the same amount you saved, wouldn't it?

Comment: You don’t need simulation software for this, just good intuition, maybe this will help. The signal propagates in the dielectric between the microstrip trace and the ground underneath it. It does not travel down the microstrip and *then* back on the ground plane. The return currents due to the signal going through the caps will travel exactly under the caps, regardless of their orientation. So whether you orient them parallel or perpindicular, the return path is under them and then back down the main line. To first order, the orientation has no impact at this frequency (~6” wavelength in FR4).

Answer (score 0):

That post isn't a good reference, and illustrates the hazard of relying on unsourced, poorly supported internet opinions.  High reputation only reflects upon a user's persistence and relative success on the platform, and not the accuracy of their opinions on any particular subject.

Not having a simulator myself, my feeling is that the longer trace lengths will impair performance in the cutoff band (so, harmonics).  Lateral coupling is small in planar designs, so it doesn't do anything to route them "in parallel".  Even so, the coupled length simply manifests as a tapped inductor of low coupling coefficient, giving different phase to the zeroes thus introduced, without reducing their effect in the first place.

In lumped-element terms, the shunt ESL (trace + body + via lengths) adds zeroes to the transfer function.  But at very high frequencies (10s GHz?), TL and wave effects may be necessary to model anyway, and a lumped-element model again loses usefulness.

It also might not matter very much:

- The filter is probably not very sharp (precise, high order), so merely follow the suggested layout and component values (that includes component sizes).  Tolerances likely don't need to be extreme (10% good enough?), because the transition band will be a bit above carrier, and the lower harmonics get only modest attenuation.
- Matching: again probably not very precise, whether due to allowable VSWR being generous (3:1 or more?), the matching ratio being small, or because the load is wholly unknown to begin with and must be tuned by hand (in lieu of a simulator to solve for it at design time) -- the last case might end up quite precise, but first-design precision happens to be irrelevant.

These are, of course, several assumptions here, which might not be true in a given case.  One must then find information to support or discredit them, and reshape ones' motivations accordingly.

Preferably, these data would be found from the manufacturer.  But, say, full impedance / scattering params. are not always available.  Often all you get is, say, a module with a required circuit and layout, and that's that; nothing to check, nothing to design, only hope and pray it works.

And even so, "works" is often a matter of opinion: does the Bluetooth work from seemingly adequate range?  Does the WiFi radio connect at reasonable bandwidth?  Does the cell modem receive enough bars?  Etc.  Rarely is the signal level measurable and testable, and time taken to optimize it to the fullest extent.  (Signal strength stats are at least helpful here, but not all radios provide them, or more than the most basic measures thereof.)

These are, again, all eminently solvable issues; the problem is the lack of background information to pursue them, or the project time or budget.  (Modules at least help with that, where manufacturers, at least have more opportunity to, bring all of the above (standards, tools, knowledge, budget) to bear and make a reasonably optimal product.  The downside is when they don't tell you about the region around the problem space, i.e. how *far* certain component values can vary from the design values, and in which ways; trace lengths, impedances, layout and grounding, antenna geometry and nearby conductors; etc.

Which... all rather comes full-circle, oddly enough.  Many problems, when it comes down to it, are a matter of communication -- or rather, the problem is the failure to do so, whether by laziness, lack of budget, or other reasons.  When it comes to free advice on the internet, the issue is of course "all of the above".

---

This is, of course, just my opinion.

The philosophical lecture is probably not necessary (or warranted, or perhaps not even welcome) here specifically, but I have no better place to put it on a platform like this, and it seems at least relevant.  Perhaps I'll file this post and link it when such concerns come up from time to time...

See also: ChatGPT concerns, where similar mechanics are at work (unsourced and unjustified opinions); with the added downside that justifications can be wholly hallucinated by it, with no comments to reality-check them.  (But again, here too, plenty of opinions in narrow domains go relatively unchecked.)

I give some justification, but only hand-wavingly.  One can get at least roughly representative numbers, modeling a circuit like this, by taking lengths from the layout, computing their TL parameters (electrical length and impedance), and using that directly, or as LC equivalents, in an AC simulation.  And again, a simulator or direct measurement would really be better; and best of all, building and testing the thing in as finished of a state as is possible.

Comment: I appreciate the lengthy answer and your thoughts. I have two physical products our company produced, one using my layout (above) and another that was outsourced which does not. The product that uses the shown layout is well within performance specs while the other is not. My question is aimed at trying to determine how much this aspect matters (or not). All this said, I feel that we could have an excellent chat some time, and I gather you effectively agree that the perpendicular placement is better (or at least good enough). Overall, though, I admit feeling a bit lost at the end, here. :)

Comment: Ah, interesting, cheers.  Yeah, how much the "other" is failing by, depends on... everything; as said, one can construct a model at least hand-wavingly, but also knowing how to compare that model to what the system requires (tolerable VSWR, available signal strength, etc.) may not be well defined.